# Trying to use MSO conditions in my email, but it creates duplicate buttons when sent to outlook. How do I fix this?

Tags: html, css, email, outlook, html-email

I'm kind of new to creating my own emails and looking to learn from my mistakes. I was creating an email and wanted to add a redemption button to it through styling. I added the mso condition, but when the email was sent, it turns up like this out of outlook. In other email platforms it shows as it should (only 1 button). I am not sure what I am doing wrong and why it is showing double. [duplicate buttons](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m3sUX.png)

Here is my code:

```html
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" role="presentation" style="border-collapse:separate;line-height:100%;">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <div>
                <!--[if mso]>
                    <v:roundrect xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" xmlns:w="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word" href="@COUPONURL" style="height:40px;v-text-anchor:middle;width:300px;" arcsize="5%" strokecolor="#5cbf50" fillcolor="#5cbf50;width: 130;">
                        <w:anchorlock/>
                        <center style="color:#ffffff;font-family:Helvetica, sans-serif;font-size:18px; font-weight: 600;">Click here!</center>
                    </v:roundrect>
                <![endif]-->
                <a href="@COUPONURL" style="display: inline-block; mso-hide:all; background-color: #5cbf50; color: #FFFFFF; border:1px solid #5cbf50; border-radius: 6px; line-height: 220%; width: 300px; font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:18px; font-weight:600; text-align: center; text-decoration: none; -webkit-text-size-adjust:none;  " target="_blank">CLICK HERE TO REDEEM</a>
                </a>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Perhaps mso-hide:all needed to be on a block-level element, rather than an inline element (Outlook also ignores anything like `display: inline-block` or just block)?

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that you're only making the Outlook button conditional.

You need to add in logic to show only one OR the other.

```html
<!--[if mso]>
    Button for Outlook
<![endif]-->

<!--[if !mso]><!-- -->
    Button for everything else
<![endif]-->
```

Comment: Thank you so much!! I will test it.

Comment: I understand in the past the `<!-- -->` might have been needed, but I'm not sure this is valid today. Do test.